# How to add custom arrow for li a tag on Zurb-Foundation drilldown - dropdown?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, dropdown

Do I need to set custom arrow right for li a tag? How do that? I set my code to code pen and set a link to show you look:
https://codepen.io/pen/?editors=1010
I need to add my style for the arrow. I first time using the foundation plugin. I don't know how to style. I don't like this blue arrow i want my custom. I search on google but without success.
Thanks!

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Foundation Starter Template</title>
    <!-- jQuery must be imported before Foundation -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.2.3/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/6.2.2-rc2/foundation.min.js"></script>
<style media="screen">
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content  a{
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.is-drilldown {
  max-width: 200px!important;
  min-height: 200px!important;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}
</style>

  </head>
  <body>


  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content" style="width: 200px;min-height: 200px;
  max-width: 200px;">
      <ul class="menu" data-drilldown  data-back-button='<li class="js-drilldown-back"><a class="new-back"></a></li>'style="width: 200px;min-height: 200px;
    max-width: 200px;" id="m1">
      <li style="width: 200px;min-height: 200px;
    max-width: 200px;">
        <a href="#" >Staaas 1</a>
        <ul class="menu" style="width: 200px;min-height: 200px;
      max-width: 200px;">
          <li style="width: 200px;min-height: 200px;
        max-width: 200px;">
            <a href="#"> Item 1A</a>
            <ul class="menu " style="width: 200px;min-height: 200px;
          max-width: 200px;">
              <li style="width: 200px;min-height: 200px;
            max-width: 200px;"><a href="#Item-1Aa">Item 1Aa</a></li>
              <li><a href="#Item-1Ba">Item 1Ba</a></li>
              <li><a href="#Item-1Ca">Item 1Ca</a></li>
              <li><a href="#Item-1Da">Item 1Da</a></li>
              <li><a href="#Item-1Ea">Item 1Ea</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#Item-1B">Item 1B</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Item-1C">Item 1C</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Item-1D">Item 1D</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Item-1E">Item 1E</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content" style="width: 200px;min-height: 200px;
  max-width: 200px;">
      <ul class="menu" data-drilldown  data-back-button='<li class="js-drilldown-back"><a class="new-back"></a></li>'style="width: 200px;min-height: 200px;
    max-width: 200px;" id="m1">
      <li  >
        <a href="#" >Staaas 1</a>
        <ul class="menu"  >
          <li  >
            <a href="#"> Item 1A</a>
            <ul class="menu "  >
              <li><a href=" ">Item 1Aa</a></li>
              <li><a href="#Item-1Ba">Item 1Ba</a></li>
              <li><a href="#Item-1Ca">Item 1Ca</a></li>
              <li><a href="#Item-1Da">Item 1Da</a></li>
              <li><a href="#Item-1Ea">Item 1Ea</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#Item-1B">Item 1B</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Item-1C">Item 1C</a></li>
          <li><a href=" ">Item 1D</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Item 1E</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li >
        <a href="#" >Staaas 1</a>
        <ul class="menu"  >
          <li style="width: 200px;min-height: 200px;
        max-width: 200px;">
            <a href="#"> Item 1A</a>
            <ul class="menu " style="width: 200px;min-height: 200px;
          max-width: 200px;">
              <li  ><a href=" ">Item 1Aa</a></li>
              <li><a href="#Item-1Ba">Item 1Ba</a></li>
              <li><a href="#Item-1Ca">Item 1Ca</a></li>
              <li><a href="#Item-1Da">Item 1Da</a></li>
              <li><a href="#Item-1Ea">Item 1Ea</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#Item-1B">Item 1B</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Item-1C">Item 1C</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Item-1D">Item 1D</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Item-1E">Item 1E</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).foundation();
$('.new-back').each(function(){
  var backTxt = $(this).parent().closest('.is-drilldown-submenu-parent').find('> a').text();
  $(this).text(backTxt);
  
});
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

HTML: